# Is this the dual in Scottish Gaelic?

Tags: grammatical-number, celtic, irish

The wikipedia article for inflection has [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:D%C3%A0_ch%C3%B9.png).

The picture is comprised of three labeled images:

- A single dog labeled *cù*
- Two dogs labeled *dà chù*
- Three dogs labeled *coin*

The description on the article reads:

> Inflection of the Scottish Gaelic lexeme for "dog", which is cù for singular, chù for dual with the number dà ("two"), and coin for plural

This piqued my interest, because although I don't know any Scottish Gaelic this looks very similar to the Irish. In Irish this would be *cú*, *dhá chú*, *chunna* (*cú* is a little more specific than dog in Irish, I don't know if this is the case in Scottish Gaelic, but this isn't a question of semantics).

However Irish doesn't have a dual (or it is extremely marginal).  What's happening in Irish is two things:

- The Irish word for two *dhá*, triggers lenition on the noun it modifies.
- Irish nouns modified by a number are (usually) not inflected as plural. *cú* is not one of those cases so it is not plural.

So the thing that looks dual *chú* is really a lenited form of *cú*. Three hounds would be *trí **cú***, and four would be *ceithre **chú***.

If I were to take this image and simply translate it to Irish, it would look remarkably similar, but would be very misleading. So I'm suspicious that since Scottish Gaelic is so closely related to Irish that the same thing might be happening.  I looked at the description of the image on wikimedia commons which reads:

> 1, 2, 3 dogs – in Scottish Gaelic *cù*, *dà chù*, *trì **coin***.

(emphasis mine)

This appears to go against my hypothesis. If this is correct, Scottish Gaelic does mark nouns in the plural even when they are modified by a number, unlike Irish. From what little I know of Welsh, I believe Welsh behaves like Irish in this respect which would suggest this is a Scottish innovation.

So I check wiktionary and:

- *chù* is a lenited form of *cù*
- *dà* triggers lenition
- furthermore it says *dà* "usually" takes the singular dative
- no dual form is listed for *cù*
- *trì* does appear to take the plural (I had to infer this from the example sentences)

This suggests to me that *chù* as it appears in the diagram is a lenited form of *cù*, and it is probably singular, but it may be that the singular and dual forms are identical.

At this point I was wondering if Scottish even had a dual form so I checked [Scottish Gaelic grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Gaelic_grammar) on Wikipedia which reads:

> Dual forms of nouns are only found after the numeral *dà* (two), where they are obligatory. The dual form is identical in form to the dative singular; depending on noun class, the dual is therefore either the same in form as the common singular (the nominative-accusative, Class 1 nouns, Class 3 and Class 4 nouns), or have a palatalised final consonant in nouns of Class 2 and Class 5.

This doesn't cite any source inline, but it does line up with what I had guessed. However it does at a surface level seem to contradict what wiktionary says. It seems likely that wiktionary and wikipedia's source are giving different analyses of the same underlying facts.

From here I check the Old Irish etymon. In Old Irish the dual form is *coin* (nom.), the Scottish "dual" *cù* seems more likely to have descended from the Old Irish singular form than the dual form. Which is a bit curious to me.

---

Is my synthesis of the information I have correct? Is there something crucial I am missing? Is my description of what's happening here correct?

And is this "dual" a Scottish a remnant of an earlier less marginal dual system, or an innovation from something more like what is found in Irish? I think putting this in relation with Irish would help me to understand better.

Comment: The Scottish system is essentially the same as the Irish one. The main difference is that numerals higher than 2 generally also take the singular in Irish, except in a number of words that take the regular plural (_cinn_, _orlaí_, etc.) or have a special ‘count plural’ (_bliana_, _seachtaine_, etc.) – [this article](https://researchrepository.ucd.ie/rest/bitstreams/9802/retrieve) has a lot of detail on that. The dative is less stable in Irish than in Scottish, but it is still used after _dhá_; in the standard language, mainly for body parts (_chluais_, _chois_, _láimh_), but dialectally also →

Comment: → more generally (e.g., _dhá bhróig_, _dhá fhuinneoig_). So I’d say the description on Wikipedia is correct. Wiktionary’s description isn’t incorrect either, really: since duals are found only after the numeral _dà_, which lenites, dual forms are always lenited – so is the lenition in _chù_ an inherent part of the dual form? You could argue either way. I’ve also seen arguments that neither Irish nor Scottish have duals; different numerals just take different singular/plural forms depending on the noun (similar to how some Slavic numerals take the genitive, others the nominative).